# Clicking a thumbnail in a uicollectionviewcell and displaying full image in a new view

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using a UIViewController with a UICollectionView to render a series of thumbnails to in the view.

When the user clicks the thumbnail it should bring them to a new scene that displays the full image.

I tried using `didSelectItemAt` to implement this but when testing it no output log is produced:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Selecting item #\(indexPath.row)")
}
```

The thumbnail pictures are displayed properly with the following:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = imageCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as! ImageGalleryCell

    if cellCount < imageArray.count{
        print("Cell Count: ", cellCount)

        let url = URL(string: "https://myurl.com\(imageArray[cellCount])")
        print("url: ", url!)
       cell.images.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "someImage"))
    }
    cellCount += 1
    return cell
}
```

Is `didSelectItemAt`  the proper method to use to click an thumbnail image and display a full image in a new view?

EDIT: I tried to use a segue as follows:

```
 `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toFullImage"{
        if let toFullImage = segue.destination as? ImagePageController{
            toFullImage.fullImage = UIImage(named: fullImageArray[0])!
        }
    }
}`
```

But when I click on an image the app crashes and I get an error saying: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Is it possible to fix it so it can work with segue or is this completely wrong?

Comment: Yes, this would be the proper method. Have you set the `delegate` of your collectionView?

Comment: Yes I've set the delegate and dataSource:
       `imageCollection.dataSource = self`
       `imageCollection.delegate = self`

Comment: I would put a breakpoint (you can put it just before returning a cell for example) and make sure that `allowsSelection` is `true`, the `delegate` _is_ my controller instance and nothing is in front of the collectionView or cell "stealing" touches... I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: Can you clarify?